# Using STARTUPINFOEX in CreateProcess

Tags: c, winapi

Many places I saw that we can use startupinfoex structure in CreateProcess function. But when I checked the signature is only allowing startupinfo structure. Can anybody please give a snippet how startupinfoex can be used with createprocess function. Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to cast the `STARTUPINFOEX*` to a `STARTUPINFO*`.

Be sure to pass the `EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT` flag to `dwCreationFlags` and set the `StartupInfo.cb` member to `sizeof(STARTUPINFOEX)`.

Comment: Isn't it a better solution to pass &startup_info.StartupInfo? That avoids the cast. Casts are dangerous because they are too powerful, whereas &startup_info.StartupInfo stays within the bounds of the type system.